# How to detect keyboard type changes with the size, type, suggestion bar height of new keyboard type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard, custom-keyboard

Is there any way to detect keyboard types changes with the size, type and suggestion bar height, change like from English keyboard to Hindi which contains some kind of suggestion bar (see screenshot).

**Normal English Keyboard**

[image]
[image]

> **First Problem**

**After changing to Hindi LIPI** - When just I changed, everthing is fine because size of english and hindi keyboard is same, but after start typing Hindi Lipi suggestion cover the `TextField`

[image]
[image]

> **Second Problem**

**After changing to Emoji** - Emoji keyboard hight little bit more as compare to english, So again keyboard cover the `TextField`.

[image]

Comment: textfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

Comment: I already using`UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo` but it only hide suggestion for English not for Hindi Lipi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an observer for a notification named "UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification".

The "userInfo" dictionary for the notification has multiple frames of the keyboard on the screen.

**adding an observer**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(logNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

**selector with the logger**

```
- (void)logNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"%@", notification);
}
```

**userInfo dictionary content**

```
userInfo = {
    UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 7;
    UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = 0;
    UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 216}}";
    UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 441.5}";
    UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 460}";
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 315}, {320, 253}}";
    UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 352}, {320, 216}}";
    UIKeyboardIsLocalUserInfoKey = 1;
}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Same problem i too faced. And I resolved by using below code

```
CGSize keyboardSize = [aNotification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

Use UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey instead of using UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4

**Register Observer**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector:#selector(KeyboardWillChangeFrame),name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame,object: nil)
```

**Function**

```
    @objc func KeyboardWillChangeFrame(_ notification: Notification){
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        print("New Keyboard Height:",keyboardHeight)
     }
}
```

Comment: should i use this insteed of UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and hide notification?

Comment: No, you should use it with show and hide notification to be able to handle everything

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the height of the Keyboard as per presented on the screen

- UIKeyboardWillShowNotification is sent with a keyboard height of 224

Register observers against the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];    
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Set a global variable for keyboard height:

```
CGFloat _currentKeyboardHeight = 0.0f;
```

Implement **keyboardWillShow**  and **keyboardWillHide** to react to the current change in keyboard height:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
   NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
   CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
   CGFloat deltaHeight = kbSize.height - _currentKeyboardHeight; 
   // Write code to adjust views accordingly using deltaHeight
   _currentKeyboardHeight = kbSize.height;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
   NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
   CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
   // Write code to adjust views accordingly using kbSize.height
   _currentKeyboardHeight = 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: Please read question carefully. I'm asking for when keyboard type changed not keyboard appear or disappear notification. Because some keyboard like Emoji have different size. `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` notification not fired when we change the keyboard type.