# Input in react native gifted chat is covered by keyboard

Tags: reactjs, keyboard, chat, native

I'm facing a problem with the Android version.

I'm using gifted chat for my application chat. But the text input is covered by the keyboard so I can't see what I'm typing.

I'm using react-native version 0.51. I already followed couples of solutions but it still not working.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420468/keyboardavoidingview-not-working-properly) that uses keyboardAvoidingView and also added KeyboardSpacer and its also not working.

Any advice would be very great.

Here's my render component code

```
render() {
console.log(this.state);
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <GiftedChat
      messages={this.state.messages}
      onSend={Fire.shared.send}
      loadEarlier={this.state.loadEarlier}
      isLoadingEarlier={this.state.isLoadingEarlier}

      user={{
        name: this.props.profile.name,
        _id: this.props.profile.user_id,
        avatar: this.props.profile.profile_image
      }}

      renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
      renderActions={this.renderCustomActions}
      renderAvatar={this.renderAvatar}
      renderBubble={this.renderBubble}
      renderSend={this.renderSend}
      renderSystemMessage={this.renderSystemMessage}
      renderCustomView={this.renderCustomView}
      renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
    />
    <KeyboardSpacer/>
  </View>
)}
```

Comment: did you try to set keyboardVerticalOffset value?

Comment: Yes i did, but its still not working :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also same issue. I solved it using adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in **AndroidManifest.xml** file as below :

```xml
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  ...
  ...
  >
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    ...
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" <!-- add here -->
  >
    ...
  </activity>
  ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 11):

Looks like this is a common issue with React Native Gifted Chat and Expo on Android devices.

You could use the `react-native-keyboard-spacer` package to keep the content visible after opening the keyboard:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import KeyboardSpacer from 'react-native-keyboard-spacer';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';

export default class Chat extends Component {
  render() {
    const giftedChatMessages = [
      ...
    ];
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <GiftedChat
          messages={giftedChatMessages}
          onSend={newMessages => onSend(newMessages[0].text)}
          user={{
              _id: 1,
          }}
          renderAvatar={() => null}
        />
        {Platform.OS === 'android' ? <KeyboardSpacer /> : null }
      </View>   
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
import { KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <GiftedChat
    messages={this.state.messages}
    onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
    user={{
      _id: 1,
    }}
  />
  {Platform.OS === 'android' && <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" />}
</View>;
```