# Keyboard Avoiding View - React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a sign-up screen "Inputs", I want when user select input doesn't hide other, so I wrap it inside `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` and set `behavior "padding"` but after choosing some input I see a View cover all my content so I can't see any things "just white View"

So maybe I made something wrong when using it, how can I handle it?

**ScreenShot**

[image: UI]

**here's my code**

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
behavior="padding"
keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.select({
ios: () => 0,
android: () => 200,
})()}>
  <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.imgContainer}>
    <Image
    style={styles.imgStyle}
    resizeMode="cover"
    source={require('../../assets/Logo.png')}
    />
    </View>
    <View>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Icon
      style={styles.iconStyle}
      name="md-person"
      size={20}
      color="#ddf"
      />
      <TextInput
      onChangeText={value => this.setState({userName: value})}
      value={userName}
      style={styles.inputStyle}
      placeholder="Name"
      />
      </View>
      <View
      style={{
      marginTop: 0,
      marginLeft: 16,
      marginBottom: 0,
      }}>
      <Text>{this.state.NameValid}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Icon
      style={styles.iconStyle}
      name="md-at"
      size={20}
      color="#ddf"
      />
      <TextInput
      onChangeText={value => this.setState({email: value})}
      value={email}
      style={styles.inputStyle}
      placeholder="Email"
      keyboardType="email-address"
      />
      </View>
      <View
      style={{
      marginTop: 0,
      marginLeft: 16,
      marginBottom: 0,
      }}>
      <Text>{this.state.emailValid}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Icon
      style={styles.iconStyle}
      name="md-call"
      size={20}
      color="#ddf"
      />
      <TextInput
      style={styles.inputStyle}
      placeholder="mobile"
      onChangeText={value => this.setState({phoneNumber: value})}
      value={phoneNumber}
      keyboardType="phone-pad"
      />
      </View>
      <View
      style={{
      marginTop: 0,
      marginLeft: 16,
      marginBottom: 0,
      }}>
      <Text>{this.state.phoneValid}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{...styles.inputContainer, marginBottom: 0}}>
      <Icon
      style={styles.iconStyle}
      name="md-lock"
      size={20}
      color="#ddf"
      />
      <TextInput
      secureTextEntry
      style={styles.inputStyle}
      placeholder="Password"
      value={password}
      onChangeText={value => this.setState({password: value})}
      />
      </View>
      <View
    style={{
    marginTop: 0,
    marginLeft: 16,
    marginBottom: 0,
    }}>
    <Text>{this.state.passwordValid}</Text>
    </View>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => this.signUp()}
      style={styles.btnStyle}>
      <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {color: '#fff', fontSize: 20}]}>
      Sign Up
      </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {opacity: 0.7}]}>
        Do you have account?
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignIn')}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}> sign In </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  imgContainer: {alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 25},
  imgStyle: {width: 250, height: 150},
  inputContainer: {
    margin: 15,
    marginBottom: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderRadius: 30,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  iconStyle: {
    marginLeft: 15,
  },
  inputStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    width: '85%',
    textAlign: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'right' : 'left',
  },
  buttonsContainer: {
    margin: 15,
    marginBottom: 20,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  btnStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#1E558E',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
  textContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 25,
  },
  textStyle: {color: '#1E558E', fontSize: 17},
});
```

Comment: the issue with ```keyboardVerticalOffset```. check https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11681 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420468/keyboardavoidingview-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

No need of KeyboardAvoidingView(as I am using it for Android(didn't checked in iOS with this way)), you can wrap your screen with ScrollView having the most outer component inside ScrollView minHeight: 100% or height from Dimensions(as you wish) to cover full screen, and it defaultly makes it avoid keyboard covering your input view and also you can scroll through the view above Keyboard if you are using ScrollView when it makes the adjustment by making your view just above the keyboard. Using latest versions up-to-date.